# Transforming a map in Scala

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, scala-collections

I would like to transform a map of type `String -> List[String]` in Scala such that each `(k, (List v1, v2, ... vn))` key-value pair leads to the pairs `{(k:v1, k), (k:v2, k), ... (k:vn, k)}`.

For example, I would like to transform

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(A -> List(a1, a2), B -> List(b1))
```

to

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(A:a1 -> A, A:a2 -> A, B:b1 -> B)
```

I was able to get partway to my goal using [this answer][1]:

```
scala> val schema = Map("A" -> List("a1", "a2"),  "B" -> List("b1"))
schema: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(A -> List(a1, a2), B -> List(b1))

scala>  schema flatten {case(k, vs) => vs.map((_, k))}
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(String, String)] = List((a1,A), (a2,A), (b1,B))
```

When I try prepending the original key and a colon to each value, I get an error:

```
scala> schema flatten {case(k, vs) => vs.map((k.concat(":").concat(_), k))}
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String => String, String)
 required: String => ?
       schema flatten {case(k, vs) => vs.map((k.concat(":").concat(_), k))}
```

Comment: `flatten`? Since when does anyone use `flatten` instead of `flatMap`?

Comment: @TimothyJones Nothing is wrong with `flatten`. But abusing the implicit function argument to make it act as if it were a `flatMap` is really ugly. One should keep in mind that this implicit function parameter exists only to make the type-checker happy by converting the type parameter `A` into an `Iterable[B]` for some `B`. In strictly typed programming languages which can express this constraint without an implicit conversion function, or in untyped languages, `flatten` wouldn't even accept any arguments at all. `flatten` should implement the fundamental monadic "multiply". It takes no args.

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed it results in the wrong return type in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no `_` and no variable in `(k.concat(":").concat(k), k)`, so it's not a function literal, but the argument to `map` must be a function.
2. You don't want to concatenate `k` with `k` anyway

Try this:

```
schema.flatMap { case (k, vs) => vs.map(v => (k + ":" + v, k)) }
```

or even more concisely:

```
for ((k, vs) <- schema; v <- vs) yield (k + ":" + v, k)
```

---

**EDIT**

For each `k`, the expression `k.concat(":").concat(_)` is a function that takes a string `s` and computes `k + ":" + s`.

Therefore, `(k.concat(":").concat(_), k)` is a tuple of

1. A function `x => k.concat(":").concat(x)` and
2. the value `k`

So it has type `(String => String, String)`. That's different from `String => (String, String)`, and that's still not what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I did make a mistake in my post, which I fixed in response to your answer. I still get an error when I switch to `(k.concat(":").concat(_), k)`, albeit a different one.

Comment: Andrey, thank you so much for answering both parts of my original and edited question. I appreciate understanding what I did wrong, how to fix it, and the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that `.map` takes a function of the form `String => ?`, but you're passing it a tuple of `(String, String)`.

`(k.concat(":").concat(k), k)` is not a function - also I think you didn't mean to put `k` twice in the `concat`.

To create the map, you want a function with signature `String => (String, String)`

- `vs.map((k.concat(":").concat(k),k))` incorrectly passes `(String, String)` to map
- `vs.map((k.concat(":").concat(_),k))` incorrectly passes `(String => String, String)` to map.
- `vs.map(v => (k.concat(":").concat(v), k))` correctly matches `String => (String, String)`.

We can then get:

```
schema flatten {case(k, vs) => vs.map(v => (k.concat(":").concat(v), k)) }
 //  List((A:a1,A), (A:a2,A), (B:b1,B))
```

You can see this code in action [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mYJWkCn3T6qRSep2OeWdTg).

However, as Andrey's excellent comment points out, it's not good practice to use `flatten` with an implicit function. Also, you want a `Map` rather than a `List`. For these two reasons, I think you should use `flatMap` instead of `flatten`:

```
schema flatMap {case(k, vs) => vs.map(v => (k.concat(":").concat(v), k)) };
// Map(A:a1 -> A, A:a2 -> A, B:b1 -> B)
```

See [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vqdpMFG2TOWmgSFIHioMEA) if you want to try it out.

Comment: Thank you. As you surmised, I did make a mistake in my post. See updated question and comment to Andrey.

Comment: This answer is different to Andrey's - did it work for you?